# How to insert form in DataBase

Tags: forms, 8

I created my form but inserting the base does not work also radios type does not appear in the form

```php
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\contact_form\Form\ContributeForm.
 */

namespace Drupal\contact_form\Form;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ChangedCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CssCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;

/**
 * Contribute form.
 */

class ContributeForm extends FormBase implements FormInterface{
    protected $accepted_domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com'];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'contact_form_contribute_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $form['FullName'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Full Name'),
            '#required' => TRUE,

        );
        $form['Email'] = array(
            '#type' => 'email',
            '#title' => $this->t('Email address'),
            '#required' => true,
            '#size' => 60,
            '#maxlength' => 128,

        );

        $form['Feedback'] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => $this->t('Feedback'),
            '#description' => t('Type of feedback'),
            '#default_value' => 0,
            '#options' => array(
                0 =>'Comments or suggestions',
                1 => 'Questions',
                2 =>'Report a problem(s)',
                3 =>'Other',
            )
        );
        $form['Subject'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Subject'),
            '#required' => true,
        );
        $form['Message'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#title' => $this->t('Your Message'),
            '#required' => true,
            '#cols' => 90,
            '#rows' => 10,
        );

        $form['captcha'] = array(
            '#type' => 'captcha',
            '#captcha_type' => 'recaptcha/reCAPTCHA',
            '#title' => $this->t('Captcha:'),
            '#required' => true,
        );

        $form['save'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#input' => TRUE,
            '#value' => 'save',
            '#submit' => array('buildForm')
        );


        return array(
            '#form' => $form,
            '#theme' => 'contribute',


        );

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $name = $form_state->getValue('FullName');
        $email = $form_state->getValue('Email');
        $subject = $form_state->getValue('Subject');
        $type = $form_state->getValue('TypeFeedback');
        $msg = $form_state->getValue('Message');
        $field = array(

            'FullName' =>  $name,
            'Email' => $email,
            'TypeFeedback' =>  $type ,
            'Subject' => $subject,
            'Message' =>  $msg,
            'Etat_message'=>  '',
            'Date_contact'=>  '',
            'adresse_IP'=>  '',
        );
        db_insert('contact')
            ->fields($field)
            ->execute();
        drupal_set_message("succesfully saved");


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to create a services to store in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `#submit` key fixed the submission issue for me:

```php
$form['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#value' => 'save',
    //'#submit' => array('buildForm')
);
```

DB insert works correctly.

If you do `return $form;` in the `buildForm()` method, the radios form element is rendered correctly. Looks like your theme might be causing the issue.

Comment: You can't return the form as #something. It must be a real render array, otherwise it doesn't get parsed. If you want a theme function, use #theme on the render array.

Comment: I understood nothing of what the solution

Comment: @sony, in your `public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)` replace the `form['save']` array with the snippet above. And replace your `return array('#form' => $form, '#theme' => 'contribute');` with `return $form;`. That will fix the issue.

Comment: @mkudenko, how to do it exactly?

Comment: I do this because I have a theme to a form theming (contribute.html.twig)

Comment: @sony copy and paste

Comment: @ mkudenko when I write like this theme does not work